# Can I make Storm's UI expect a different service principal from "HTTP"

Tags: authentication, apache-storm, kerberos

I have Storm working on my own Kerberos realm, but in order to connect to my corporate realm, I'm beholden to their rules. There is only one production AD, so I need to make non-prod and prod versions of all principals. Thus far, I have changed my Storm cluster config to use "storm_np" in non-prod and everything works. (i.e. **storm_np@REALM** and **storm_np/HOST@REALM**)

However, the UI seems to always try to run as **HTTP/HOST@REALM** so I can't get in. Before I changed the principals, I would kinit as **HTTP@REALM** and I could see the UI just fine. Now, I'm not sure how to (1) tell the UI to run as a different principal and (2) kinit locally so i can get to it

I'm hoping for a property of some kind. To make the "storm_np" changes, I was able to change startup properties and jaas configs. I'd love to find the same for this.

Comment: On further research, I think 'storm' and 'HTTP' are supposed to be the way they are as they are service names, and prod/non-prod are identified by the attached hostname. e.g. **storm/non-prod-host@REALM** and **storm/prod-host@REALM**. The only problem with that is that storm supervisors need a client principal (**storm/REALM**) and that principal, because it has no host could be used to connect to both the prod and non-prod nimbuses. I'm a little uncomfortable by that but I don't see an alternative

Comment: Take a deep breath and start again... Active Directory has back-ported Kerberos a few years ago, but it uses some workarounds -- for instance, you don't create a SPN (Service Principal Name i.e. `service_type/host_DNS_canonical_name@REALM`) as such, you create an AD **service account** (with pwd) then **map a SPN** on it; and optionally you can even map multiple SPNs on the same account, cf. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/717.service-principal-names-spns-setspn-syntax-setspn-exe.aspx

Comment: My 2 cents: add an "Active Directory" tag, and maybe some Microsoft black wizard (such as T-Heron) will give you a hand.

Comment: Thank you. That additional detail was helpful because I'm also working with our AD people and was having trouble explaining what I need them to do in order to get those Kerberos service principals. I'm going to leave this open until I know I have what I need, but I think your comment was the key. Thanks